# How to use formula translated in French

Tags: openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to edit excel files, and I've experienced something weird.

Considering a worksheet called ws, if I try to apply a formula like

```
ws["A3"] = "=MAX(A1:A2)"
```

This will work fine, however if I apply

```
ws["A3"] = "=MOYENNE(A1:A2)"
```

or

```
ws["A3"] = "=MEAN(A1:A2)"
```

Nothing will work. It will write the formula in the cell but it won't be executed without opening the excel workbook with Microsoft Office to do it by hand. It is the same for every function that has a French translation.

Does someone has any clue that could help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use English spelling and syntax in the formulae because this is how they are stored in the file format. So, also use decimal points and commas to separate parameters.